# Is there a way to get past the 426 error in newsapi without upgrading?

Tags: javascript, fetch, newsapi

So, I am getting the 426:upgrade required while trying to make requests from a device. I searched about it and somewhere I found out that they said, "It can be fixed from backend" how?

Comment: which newsapi, exactly. share a link, please.

Answer (score 0):

You're maxing out your allotted daily requests, as per https://newsapi.org/pricing you only get a limited amount per tier (assuming you are using the free tier) you cannot bypass this without upgrading or doing limit control on your end by storing the responses wisely instead of calling the API every time, some people do load balancing between multiple API keys (which isn't something I would recommend); you would either have to utilize your quota smarter or since your are honestly using the service, pay for additional slots.